# Is it possible to compare a short sub-string with a hashed long string

Tags: string, algorithm, hash

I only have the hash value of a long string, but I cannot access the content of it.

Now I have a new short string, which could be contained by the long string. I need to identify if the long string contains the short string or not.

```
Integer longStringHash = 352736;

String shortString = "hello world";

if (compare(hash(shortString), longStringHash) == 1) {
  ;// wow, they are very close!
}
```

Are there any algorithms for this purpose?

ps. The length of the shortString is smaller than that of the longString .

Comment: It depends on the hash you're using, but the most realistic answer is no.

Comment: Do you know the length of the long string? There are an infinity of strings with a given hash. There probably is an infinity of strings with a given hash and containing the short string. So in theory : yes. In practice : very hard to say.

Comment: No, it can't be done. Hashing is a one way operation.

Comment: The very nature of any hash function is destructive. You cannot recreate the original text from its hash (unless you bruteforce it and hope you don't get collisions but that could take eons) and if you cannot recreate the original text from its hash - you cannot check if the shorter string you have was part of that text to begin with. Unless it's a very crappy and predictive hash function, that is, but even then chances are slim to none.

Comment: If you know the length is 20, a bruteforce will work, but it probably will last decades. If you have some more information (hash weakness like with MD5, statistical probability of words in long string), you might get results pretty fast. You cannot be sure it's the correct long string though.

Comment: Actually, since the hash is an Integer, you "only" have to check about 4.3 billions strings before finding a collision. It shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: There are schemes where similar data will hash to close values. Hashing isn't always about uniqueness, see SimHash

Comment: There are 2^160 possible 20-byte strings. There are 2^64 possible 64-bit integers. Thus each hash value corresponds to about 2^96 strings. Out of these 2^96 strings, about 2^80 (=2^96/2^16) start with your two-character substring. So yes it is possible to write such a function. Just make it always return true.

Comment: @n.m. Exactly my point. Thanks. Note that Java Integers are 32-bit, so there are even more collisions. Edit: Oh. It might not be Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have the hash as information, you cannot talk about "the long string":

- There are an infinity of strings with a given hash.
- There are an infinity of strings with a given hash and beginning with a given substring.
- There are bazillions of 20-byte `longString`s containing a given 2-byte `shortString` with a given hash.
- If your hash is only a 32-bit or 64-bit Integer (as opposed to a 512-bit SHA2), it's very feasible to bruteforce the search.

Here's a small Java Code proving that it's possible:

```
public class CheckLongHash
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String shortString = "hello world ";
        String longString = "hello world fqgr46bnnevab";
        Integer goal = 352736;
        System.out.println(longString.startsWith(shortString) &&
                longString.hashCode() == goal);
        // true
    }
}
```

Is `"hello world fqgr46bnnevab"` *THE* long string? Probably not. Does it pass the specs? Yes.